# Editing Phonegap 3.0+ plugins

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We have an iOS/Android application built using Phonegap 3.3. This app uses the barcode plugin and in general works well, however, we need to change the barcode scanner screen overlay. This has not been an issue on all versions of iOS or on pre phonegap 3.0 Android as the plugin files are compiled with the project.

The issue we are having is that the recent phonegap plugins for android seem to use a pre-compiled library as editing the source to the barcode has no affect on the output files. Can anyone tell us what we need to do to be able to use the modified Android barcode plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not modifying the plugin in the right place?

In a phonegap 3 plugin, the android part of the plugin can be found in

- projectroot/plugins/plugin.package.id/src/android/src/...
- projectroot/platforms/android/src/...

I assume you're modifying directly the plugin in projectroot/platforms/android/src/ as you've been doing before phonegap 3.

The issue is that each time you run `phonegap build android`, the content of projectroot/platforms/android is overwritten with the content at the root of the project (www folder, config.xml, plugins).

You need either to make your changes in the projectroot/plugins folder, or if you prefer to make changes in eclipse (so in platforms/android) you have to copy the modified files to projectroot/plugins if you don't want to loose your changes.